# first time working with lists in C unhandled exception

Tags: c, list, exception, unhandled

I'm trying to write a simple program that gets a list from the user (a list is a struct with data, and a pointer to the next list), and then print it.
My code is working fine, but after printing, I get an error "Unhandled exception at 0x011e1502 in exercise 4.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xcdcdcdcd."

Can anyone tell me why? here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef int list_data;
typedef struct list
{
    list_data number;
    struct list* next_list;
} list; //definition of a list
list* create_list()
{
    list* anchor;
    anchor=(list*)malloc(sizeof(list));
    anchor->next_list=NULL;
    return anchor; // allocates a memory for a list and returns address of first block
}
list* insert_list(list* current_position,list_data x)
{
    list* temp;
    temp=(list*)malloc(sizeof(list));
    temp->number=x;
    temp->next_list=current_position->next_list;
    current_position->next_list=temp;
    return temp; //inserts a new block with a data of x 
}
void printlist(list* anchor)
{
    list* current_list=anchor->next_list;
    while(current_list!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%3d -> ",current_list->number);
        current_list=current_list->next_list;
    }
    printf("End\n");
}
void scan_list(list* anchor)
{
    int num1=1;
    list* current_position=anchor;
    printf("Enter values until 0\n");
    while(num1!=0)
    {
        scanf("%d",&num1);
        if(num1)
            current_position=insert_list(current_position,num1);
    }
}
void main()
{
    list* anchor;
    anchor=create_list();
    scan_list(anchor);
    printf("\n");
    printlist(anchor);
    free(anchor);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: It's working fine for me. how are you executing it?

Comment: Only `free`ing `anchor` = memory leak. Also, it would be nice if you can explicitly state **which line** gives you that access violation error.

Comment: printf("%3d -> ",current_list->number); gave me the error but it seems to be working now. A simple reboot seemed to solve it. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: @OriaGruber, Don't worry about it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accessing an unitialized memory-area, which is denoted by the value `0xcdcdcdcd`. You must not simply `free` your list by deleting the first element, but by deleting all elements, iterating through your list and freeing every node, because you would create a memory-leak otherwise

```
void free_list(list* anchor){
    list* temp = anchor->next_list;
    free(anchor);
    while(temp->next_list){
       list* l = temp->next_list;
       free(temp);
       temp = l->next_list;
    }
}
```

Additionally, set the next element explicitly to `NULL`, when adding a node and you are having a weird cross-reference in your function

```
list* insert_list(list* current_position,list_data x)
{
    list* temp;
    temp=(list*)malloc(sizeof(list));
    temp->number=x;
    //temp->next_list=current_position->next_list; -> doesn't make sense
    current_position->next_list=temp;
    temp->next_list = NULL; //set to NULL
    return temp; //inserts a new block with a data of x 
}
```

I think four you have not explicitly told that the `next` item is `NULL` you are iterating past the actual end of the list.

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted is working fine. It is taking values from user and displaying it correctly.
I have compiled the code using linux gcc and made some modification to avoid some warning